# Пропадает панель задач во время записи экрана

Tags: linux, linux-mint

В Linux Mint 17.3 во время записи экрана (recordmydesktop) и при показе экрана через скайп прекращает отображаться панель задач. При завершении записи/показа появляется снова.

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 2):

Проблема конкретно циннамона, только багрепорт - циннамнон считает часть "экранозаписывателей" полноэкранными приложениями, в следствии чего прячет панель.

Comment: Большинство? Я вообще нашёл только один. И ещё пару оболочек для него. Есть ещё другие? Можно пример?

Comment: Поправлюсь - часть

Comment: А какие не считает?

Comment: @Qwertiy, честно - не знаю